# Displaying image from directory to html page using Flask Python

Tags: python, html, flask

Here, I want to inster an image from the directory to html page. I know how to do it using the exact file name but now I'm trying to do it using a variable which refers to the image name.

This is my python file where I save the image name to the database. The picture is already saved in the directory before.

```
//code.py
@app.route('/add_picture', methods=['POST'])
def add_picture():
    if 'user_id' in session:
        session['logged_in'] = True
        photo = request.form.get('photo')

        with sqlite3.connect('memory.db') as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            name = session['name']
            cursor.execute('''UPDATE users SET photo=? WHERE name=?''', (photo, name))
            conn.commit()

        return redirect("/settings")
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

```
//code.html
<img src="{{ url_for('.static', filename='images/IMG_2165.JPG') }}" width="200" height="200"> 
//we inster the picture by using the image name and it works

<img src="{{ url_for('.static', filename='images/{{ photo }}') }}" width="200" height="200"> 
//displaying the picture using the variable which refers to the image name but it returns nothing...
```

1- The image is already saved before in the directory.

2- I saved the image name to the database with the variable "photo".

3- The variable "photo" is being returned from another function.

4- In html I want to display the image using the variable but not the image name "IMG_2165.JPG".

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your function return the image's path as a variable (as in `return , photo, redirect('/')`) ?